# Bootstrap 4: Equal width columns using grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am attempting to make the layout of a container with a row and an accordion beneath it have equal width columns using the bootstrap grid. The problem is with aligning the data within the accordion to the top most row.

My understanding with bootstrap 4 is that the `col` class should auto-size per column so I would think all 8 columns would be the same width regardless of content.

The top looks okay but the rows below are condensed. Here is an example:

[image]

Here is my razor page below:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].Item)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].ItemDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].CorpCustomer)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].UoM)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].SummedOrder)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].SummedForecast)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].Difference)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportHighLevel[0].Week)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="accordion">
        @{int counter = 0; }
        @foreach (var dataVM in Model.CollapseReport)
        {
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading@(counter)">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse@(counter)" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse@(counter)">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.Item
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.ItemDescription
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.CorpCustomer
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.UoM
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.SummedOrder
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.SummedForecast
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.Difference
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    @dataVM.Summary.Week
                                </div>
                                </div>
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse@(counter)" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading@(counter)" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="@dataVM.Summary.CorpCustomer" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="@dataVM.Summary.Item" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add to Log" asp-page-handler="AddLog" asp-route-data="@dataVM.Summary.CorpCustomer, @dataVM.Summary.Item)" />
                        </form>
                        <div class="container">
                                    @foreach (var item in dataVM.WeeksOfData)
                                {
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.Item
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.ItemDescription
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.CorpCustomer
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.UoM
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.SummedOrder
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.SummedForecast
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.Difference
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                @item.Week
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                            }
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            counter++;
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your `btn btn-link` button nested in `<h5>`. `.btn` class from Bootstrap is with style `display: inline-block;`, which doesn't take up the 100% width.

Even you set `width: 100%;` on the button, your columns still won't be aligned because:

1. `.btn` has style of `white-space: nowrap;` hence the texts inside your collapsable heading won't wrap, while the texts inside the collapsable body will.
2. `.btn` class has .75rem padding left and right, which will take up the overall row width.
3. You have a nested container inside your collapsable body. The container has 15px padding left and right, which will take up the overall row width as well.

**Hints: you might want to think of a different design / layout.**

For example, get rid of the button nested in the heading and use anchor isntead:

```
<div class="container">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse@(i)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">Item</div>
                        <div class="col">Item Description</div>
                        <div class="col">Corp Customer</div>
                        <div class="col">UoM</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Order</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Forecase</div>
                        <div class="col">Difference</div>
                        <div class="col">Week</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse@(i)" class="collapse">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">Item</div>
                        <div class="col">Item Description</div>
                        <div class="col">Corp Customer</div>
                        <div class="col">UoM</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Order</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Forecase</div>
                        <div class="col">Difference</div>
                        <div class="col">Week</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">Item</div>
                        <div class="col">Item Description</div>
                        <div class="col">Corp Customer</div>
                        <div class="col">UoM</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Order</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Forecase</div>
                        <div class="col">Difference</div>
                        <div class="col">Week</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">Item</div>
                        <div class="col">Item Description</div>
                        <div class="col">Corp Customer</div>
                        <div class="col">UoM</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Order</div>
                        <div class="col">Summed Forecase</div>
                        <div class="col">Difference</div>
                        <div class="col">Week</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am inexperienced at web, the accordion is the best I could find for this parent child data layout. Maybe I just put the header within the button and within the nested container?

Comment: Looks really nice, got it working on my end, thank you!